# Tabs and menu in same line | Android

Tags: java, android, layout

I created an app and I use this example http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html. 
when I use the onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)  function and menu button create its shown in the first line and the line of the tabs is one behind it. How can I make the tabs and the  menu button(three dots)
be in the same line? 
I tried this

```
         requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

also this

```
         actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
         actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

and this is only removed the title and the icon and now I have one empty line with menu button(...)

this its how its look now [image: http://i.imgur.com/vfJcwwA.png]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior for non-tablet sized screens, so unless you roll your own ActionBar-isque implementation, you can't make the top ActionBar to go away as long as you have menu items.

However if you don't need the menu button, you can remove the top ActionBar entirely through

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Comment: this is the point I want The menu button.but I want it to be in the same line with the tabs

Comment: @Alon well it's simply impossible unless you write your own custom layout

Comment: Ok I understand. Their is a way to add buttons to the line of the tabs? or I have to overrirde android.support.v4.view.ViewPager and change it?

Comment: or The simple solution is to add tabs but I how can I use this ass buttons?

Comment: What do you mean by "ass buttons", do you mean the 3-dot menu button?